# How to set HTML select value with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to set selected value from an HTML dropdown from a Angular2 component. I'm failing to see if this should be working or I need something more complex

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="role" [ngModel]="SelectedRole">
    <option *ngFor="#option of Roles" [value]="option.Value">{{option.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
export class MyComponent extends Secured {
    public SelectedRole: String = "4";

    ...

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

From this code, I'd expect ítem with value `4` to be selected at the begining and that's not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
<select class="form-control" id="role" [ngModel]="selectedRole">
  <option *ngFor="let option of roles" [value]="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public selectedRole: String = "4";
  roles = [{value: '1', text: '1'}, {value: '2', text: '2'}, {value: '3', text: '3'}, {value: '4', text: '4'}]

}
```

Hint: `*ngFor` has a slightliy different syntax in beta.17 (`let` instead of `#`)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VD3bAd?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This should work like you did. Notice that could put your `select` within a form element:

```
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="role" [ngModel]="SelectedRole">
    <option *ngFor="#option of Roles" [value]="option.Value">   {{option.Text}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/J1aVclVcjJPqm1Qx9j0j?p=preview.

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find answers for particular angular versions... so while searching for this issue while using a more recent version (angular 4.4.5), I've stumbled upon this thread. However none of the answers work for me so here is my solution for newer versions, in case someone else might stumble upon this thread too :-)

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="size" name="sizeValue" #sizeValue="ngModel">
  <option *ngFor="let size of sizes" [value]="size">{{size}}</option>
</select>
```

In particular this part: **name="sizeValue" #sizeValue="ngModel"** on the select element.

Comment: Thanks. I agree about the angular versions when trying to find something for angular 4 or higher. BTW your comment was my solution.