# Using select2 Dropdown value is not binded to my article - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to bind selected value in dropdown to my article which has property of same type as dropdowns source is. But somehow when I console log my article there is no value in my property which should hold an selected dropdown value.

Here is my code:

In typescript I have :

```
article: Article;
mainGroups: Group[];
subGroups: Group[];
```

On init I'm filling mainGroups and subGroups with data, like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this._groupService.getAll().subscribe(groups => this.mainGroups = groups);
    this._groupService.getAllSubGroups().subscribe(subgroups => this.subGroups = subgroups);
  }
```

Later in html I'm looping values from my `mainGroups` and `subGroups` like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Main group:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="articleGroups" required [(ngModel)]="article.mainGroup">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="group" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups">{{group.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>

<!--Sub group-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Sub group:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="subGroup" required [(ngModel)]="article.subGroup">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="subgroup" *ngFor="let subgroup of subGroups">{{subgroup.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see guys I also wrote : `[(ngModel)]="article.mainGroup"` on first dropdown, and I said also: `[ngValue]="group" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups"`

So basically this `[ngValue]="group"` should get value out of `*ngFor` and store it into `article.mainGroup`?

But when I do an console log I can not see `article.mainGroup` property at all,  even if it's defined there in `article.ts` model.. so that means `article.mainGroup` property is empty ( because is not visible in `console.log(article`)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="size" name="sizeValue" #sizeValue="ngModel">
  <option *ngFor="let size of sizes" [value]="size">{{size}}</option>
</select>
```

Note the `#sizeValue="ngModel"`

See my original answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866804/1546042

Comment: maybe there is an issue with dash-form-control and select2 classes on option?